# Does Razor needs MVC3 or can I use it only with .NET?

Tags: nvelocity, razor

I am newbie for template engines Just I am curious is it possible to use Razor without MVC ? I want to use a template engine in .NET. I have looked at the NVelocity but razor seems more understandable to me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, not really. Razor view engine is built on top of ASP.Net but it doesn't depend on MVC framework.

You can use it in a console app if you wish.

Here's a good article demonstrating the use outside of MVC: http://buildstarted.com/2010/09/29/razor-view-engine-without-mvc-at-all/

and another one here from Andrew Nurse: http://vibrantcode.com/blog/2010/7/22/using-the-razor-parser-outside-of-aspnet.html

Answer (score 1):

You can check out [RazorEngine](http://razorengine.codeplex.com/):

> A templating engine built upon Microsoft's Razor parsing technology.
>   The RazorEngine allows you to use Razor syntax to build robust
>   templates